# Poisson formula on a disc is continuous on the closure

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

[image]

It is written that the function $u$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and $u(e^{it})=\phi(t).$ I am unable to prove the continuity. 
z
The continuity in the inside can be shown because it is harmonic and hence continuous (or since it is the convolution of two continuous functions). I am unable to show that it is continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and same as $\phi$ on the circle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365635/how-to-show-the-poisson-integral-formula-is-harmonic

Comment: @Mark, I have seen that post, but that only proves the harmonic part, not the continuity part.

Comment: I see in the second part of the answer there is proof of continuity...

Comment: Did you try showing $\lim_{r \to 1^-} \|\phi - \phi \ast P_r(e^{i.})\|_\infty = 0$ for $\phi$ continuous $2\pi$-periodic [and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) $P_r(e^{it}) = \sum_n r^{|n|} e^{int}$ ? For $\phi$ smooth or $C^1$ it is obvious from the absolute convergence of its Fourier series, in general it is a matter of the $L^1$ norm of $P_r(e^{i.})$. Thus obtaining that the harmonic extension $re^{it} \mapsto \phi \ast P_r(e^{it})$ is continuous on the closed unit disk.

Comment: @Mark, thanks, I found it on that answer and sorry also, I missed it initially.